# Setup a modern java for Android Studio

Tags: java, jdk, android-studio, jre

I have troubles setting up java 1.8 for Android Studio.

Gradle Sync says:

```
Error:Buildtools 24.0.1 requires Java 1.8 or above.  Current JDK version is 1.7.
```

Here what I've got, with the help and answers here and elsewhere:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1072      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1072      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
There is only one alternative in link group javaws (providing /usr/bin/javaws): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/javaws
Nothing to configure.
```

```
$ echo $STUDIO_JDK

$ echo $IDE_HOME 

$ echo $JDK_HOME 

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
# nothing here either
```

Even this (the path is the one in `update-alternatives`) doesn't solve it:

```
android-studio/bin $ STUDIO_JDK=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java ./studio.sh
```

It looks like I misunderstood something, such as JRE vs. JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39277713/108802), I found out that the environment variables setup in `studio.sh` where not used as I expected.

I had to go to File->Project Structure, then SDK location.

There I pasted the location of the oracle JDK I just installed:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm.... Maybe installing openjdk will solve this?

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

Hope this helps.